# Pyramid/WTForm file upload error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, multipartform-data, wtforms

I'm attempting to upload an image file (jpeg) from an iOS application via a multipart/form-data PATCH request. I'm doing this with a Pyramid web application served by Waitress. The upload works fine the first time (after the server starts/resets). However, during every additional attempt made, the previous image file (from the first request) is being used as the upload image (I'm speculating here...). Does Pyramid/WTForm cache the file from the request somehow? Any idea what's going on?

**Example:**

The JSON multipart/form-data requests coming in from the client are formatted with a 'json_metadata' field and an 'image' field. So, in my view, I'm extracting these fields separately and loading the form as follows:

```
    # Get the UpdateForm
    from ..forms import UpdateMeForm
    # Fill the form
    json_metadata = self.request.POST['json_metadata']
    image = self.request.POST['image'].file
    form  = UpdateMeForm(data=simplejson.loads(json_metadata),\
                         user=me,\
                         image=image,\
                         request=self.request)
    # Save the form
    form.save()
```

I'm then using the image within the form, along with a SQLAlchemy extension known as SQLAlchemy-ImageAttach, to save the image to an S3 bucket, create and save some thumbnails to the S3 bucket, and save their respective URLs to a PostgreSQL DB.

Everything works fine after restarting the server. Maybe I'm wrong, but I think it has something to do with how I'm handling the file (I know very little about how this is done within python).

Comment: How are you creating the form? And how are you using it?  Can you provide a complete, minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: @SeanVieira I update the question with a bit more detail. Does that help?

Comment: Looks like you send one file several times, can you post javascript code? Also if you get error in production,some servers don't proper handle patch, try use POST or PUT instead

Comment: @Janom There is no javascript. It's pure python for a REST api. What makes you think the same file is getting sent multiple times?